# How to add a class to the overarching class above of 'this' in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

My html is set up like so:

```
<div class="containerElement">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="containerElement">
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

whenever a ".element" is clicked I want to add a class to the element's ".containerElement" and only that one instance of "containerElement".

How do I add a class to that one instance of "containerElement" in javascript whenever an element is clicked, my jquery code thus far is:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
    $('.containerElement', this).addClass('highlighted');
})
```

what is the correct syntax in stead of "$('.containerElement', this)"

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by referring to the direct parent of the click event target.

```
$('.element').click(function() { 
    $(this).parent().addClass('highlighted');
})
```

Comment: `I want to add a class to the element's ".containerElement" and only that one instance of "containerElement".` why so many upvotes, when it doesn't even answer the question

Comment: He only described to whom he wan't to add the class, and my code will add the class to the first `".containerElement"` only. he didn't ask to remove the class from any other elements.

Comment: Yes, he did. `only that one instance of "containerElement".`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `closest` to get the closest ancestor with the class and `siblings` to get it's sibling elements.

```
$(this).closest('.containerElement').addClass('highlighted').siblings().removeClass('highlighted');
```